# Phaser3 no scroll bar on mobile

Tags: html, scrollbar, phaser-framework, phaserjs

while working on a phaser3 project I seem to have 2 scroll bars on Desktop (inner and outer) but none on mobile. Can someone help?

This is my phaser config:

```
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.AUTO,
        parent: 'game-container',
        width: '100%',
        height: 2500,
        disableContextMenu: true
    },
    scene: [game]
};
```

`
and this is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>game.fun</title>
</head>
<style>
    .Content {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="game-container" class="Content">
        <script src='static/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script src="static/game.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Kind of tried anything on the web

Tried removing the html scrollbars and playing with the height.

Comment: I *think* the most smartphones only show scrollbars while scrolling. On which device don't you see scrollbars? Is the website scrollable even without scrollbars?

Comment: I am using Pixel6, even when I try to scroll they are not there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the cause of the error, but how your HTML is structured. The the phaser canvas is not created in the `.Content` `div`.  This could since all the css is on the `div` it won't work otherwise.

You would have to restructure it, for the ***CSS*** to apply.
*(simply placing the `script` tags aoutside of the `div` where the phaser game canvas should be placed.)*

**something like this:**

```js
<body>
    <div id="game-container" class="Content"></div>
    <script src='static/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script src="static/game.js"></script>
</body>
```

> *May be this might solve the issue.*

Comment: I fixed it, but still have the same issue. The strange thing is that it works on an emulator but not on  a real PIXEL google 6.